# asynchronous logging with python and mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, logging, asynchronous

I need to log specific activities of my web application (Python based - SQL alchemy with Postgres) and I don't want to either dump log information on my Postgres database (why fill it up with mostly rubbish?)  or use a log file (hard to search).

Ideally I would like to throw everything in another database and do this in an asynchronous way. With the logging being asynchronous I don't need to worry about the write operation failing and breaking to code that does all the important business. Also, if I miss a few logging events, it is probably no big deal.

Mongo seems like an excellent solution since it is well suited for writing operations and easy to setup.

The problem is that I have not managed to find any python tools that cover my needs and in particular the asynchronous requirement.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check out [Motor](http://emptysquare.net/blog/introducing-motor-an-asynchronous-mongodb-driver-for-python-and-tornado/).  By default, [PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) is fire-and-forget but isn't asynchronous.  With Motor, you can log without your code hanging from the write itself nor from any write confirmation by the Mongo server.

Answer (score 4):

Using the **log collector daemon** like [Fluentd](http://fluentd.org/) / [Scribe](http://github.com/facebook/scribe/) / [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/), could be an another solution.

[image: fluentd plus mongodb]

These daemon is launched at every application nodes, and takes the logs from app processes. They buffer the logs and **asynchronously** writes out the data to other systems like MongoDB / PostgreSQL / etc. The write is done by **batches**, so it's a lot more efficient than writing directly from apps.

Here's two links of how to use Fluentd from Python, and how to put the data into MongoDB.

- [Fluentd: Data Import from Python Applications](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/python)
- [Fluentd: Store Apache Logs into MongoDB](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/apache-to-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

asynchronous logging into mongodb can be achieved by adding AsyncAppender in log4j which will refer to a real appender.

For basic understanding follow this http://wiki.python.org/jython/Log4jExample

`log4mongo` pushes data into mongo.Python driver is available at http://log4mongo.org/display/PUB/Log4mongo+for+Python

adding AsyncAppender will make logging asynchronous way

just for reference,equivalent log4j file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<appender name="MongoDB" class="org.log4mongo.MongoDbAppender" >
    <param name="hostname" value="127.0.0.1" />
    <param name="port" value="27017" />
    <param name="databaseName" value="LogDB"/>
    <param name="collectionName" value="Log" />
</appender>
<appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <param name="BufferSize" value="50000"/>
    <appender-ref ref="MongoDB"/>
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="all"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [log4mongo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/log4mongo/) available with pip:

```
pip install log4mongo
```

It allows the use of the default **logging** system.
Example (extract from the doc):

```
import logging
from log4mongo.handlers import MongoHandler

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.addHandler(MongoHandler(host='localhost'))

logger.warning('test')
```

Comment: It's not clear if this is asynchronous or blocking. The OP wants a solution which will not block.

Answer (score 0):

Try python-nosql-logger. You can use elastic & mongodb both.
https://pypi.org/project/python-nosql-logger/1.1.6/

```
pip install pymongo #"pymongo[srv]" or "pymongo[aws]"
pip install python-nosql-logger

from pynosql_logger.loggers import MongoLogger

connection_string = 'your_mongodb_connection_string'
logger = MongoLogger(connection_string)

req_json = {
      'users': {
          'first_name': 'Hitesh',
          'last_name': 'Mishra',
          'email': 'hiteshmishra708@gmail.com'
      }
  }
resp = logger.add_log(req_json)
```